# How to draw a hierarchical structure (or graph)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs

I need some help how to draw the following hierarchical diagram!
[image]

Comment: Hi, do you have a MWE or where are you struggling exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an adaptation of the example you may find in chapter 3
*Tutorial: A Petri-Net for Hagen* in the `tikz` manual.

[image]

Let's begin by putting the nodes in the right places using the `positioning` library:

```
\node [place] (x1) {X1};
\node [place] (x2) [right=of x1] {X2};
\node [place] (x3) [right=of x2] {X3};
\node [place] (y1) [above=of x1] {Y1};
\node [place] (y2) [right=of y1] {Y2};
\node [place] (y3) [right=of y2] {Y3};
\node [place] (z)  [above= 1cm of y2] {Z};
```

where I have used

```
\node [<style>] (<label for tikz>) [<placement relative to other nodes>] {<text>}
```

Since the nodes have all the same appearance, the style of the node is defined as

```
place/.style={%
        circle,
        minimum size = 1.3cm,
        draw,
},
```

where `place` is the name of the style, `circle` defines the shape and `minimum size = 1.3cm,` ensures that all the nodes' shapes are of the same size (otherwise the size depends on the text printed inside the node).

The distance between the nodes is set by `node distance`, where horizontal and vertical distances can be defined separately.
The `Z` node has a specific node distance, that overrides the default setting.

Then we connect the nodes with:

```
\draw (y1) -- (z);
\draw (y2) -- (z);
\draw (y3) -- (z);
\draw (y1) -- node [label] {W11} (x1);
\draw (y1) -- node [label] {W12} (x2);
\draw (y1) -- node [label] {W13} (x3);
\draw (y2) -- node [label] {W21} (x1);
\draw (y2) -- node [label] {W22} (x2);
\draw (y2) -- node [label] {W23} (x3);
\draw (y3) -- node [label] {W31} (x1);
\draw (y3) -- node [label] {W32} (x2);
\draw (y3) -- node [label] {W33} (x3);
```

where I have used

```
\draw (<label of start node>) -- node [<style of the label>] {<text of the label>} (<label of end node>);
```

The labels of the edges are the trickiest, because, by default, they would overlap.
So, a style was defined for all of them:

```
label/.style = {%
    fill = white,
    pos  = 0.8,
},
```

where `pos` allows to place the label on the line at a certain distance from the starting point, specified by a fraction of 1 (0: starting node, 1: ending node), and `fill = white` makes the background white, for better readability.

The resulting MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
        thick,
        node distance=2.5cm and 3cm,
        place/.style = {%
            circle,
            minimum size = 1.3cm,
            draw,
        },
        label/.style = {%
            fill = white,
            pos  = 0.8,
        },
        font=\sffamily
    ]
    \node [place] (x1) {X1};
    \node [place] (x2) [right=of x1] {X2};
    \node [place] (x3) [right=of x2] {X3};
    \node [place] (y1) [above=of x1] {Y1};
    \node [place] (y2) [right=of y1] {Y2};
    \node [place] (y3) [right=of y2] {Y3};
    \node [place] (z)  [above= 1cm of y2] {Z};
    \draw (y1) -- (z);
    \draw (y2) -- (z);
    \draw (y3) -- (z);
    \draw (y1) -- node [label] {W11} (x1);
    \draw (y1) -- node [label] {W12} (x2);
    \draw (y1) -- node [label] {W13} (x3);
    \draw (y2) -- node [label] {W21} (x1);
    \draw (y2) -- node [label] {W22} (x2);
    \draw (y2) -- node [label] {W23} (x3);
    \draw (y3) -- node [label] {W31} (x1);
    \draw (y3) -- node [label] {W32} (x2);
    \draw (y3) -- node [label] {W33} (x3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Consider upvoting/accepting: it is the preferred way to show appreciation on this site (instead of posting "thank you" comments)